# Wait for sequence of action with a Redux Observable

Tags: redux, redux-observable

I have a use case where I need to wait for a sequence of actions before I dispatch another using Redux Observables. I've seen some similar questions but I cannot fathom how I can use these approaches for my given use case.

In essence I want to do something like so:

```
action$
  .ofType(PAGINATION_CLICKED) // This action occurred.
  .ofType(FETCH_SUCCESS) // Then this action occurred after.
  .map(() => analyticsAction()); // Dispatch analytics.
```

I would also like to cancel and start that sequence over again if another action of type `FETCH_ERROR` fires for example.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Great question. The important point is that `action$` is a hot/multicast stream of all actions as they are dispatched (it's a Subject). Since it's hot we can combine it multiple times and they'll all be listening to the same stream of actions.

```
// uses switchMap so if another PAGINATION_CLICKED comes in
// before FETCH_SUCCESS we start over

action$
  .ofType(PAGINATION_CLICKED)
  .switchMap(() =>
    action$.ofType(FETCH_SUCCESS)
      .take(1) // <-------------------- very important!
      .map(() => analyticsAction())
      .takeUntil(action$.ofType(FETCH_ERROR))
  );
```

So every time we receive `PAGINATION_CLICKED` we'll start listening to that inner Observable chain that listens for a single `FETCH_SUCCESS`. It's important to have that `.take(1)` because otherwise we'd continue to listen for more than one `FETCH_SUCCESS` which might cause strange bugs and even if not is just generally best practice to only take what you need.

We use `takeUntil` to cancel waiting for `FETCH_SUCCESS` if we receive `FETCH_ERROR` first.

---

As a bonus, if you decide you want also to do some analytics stuff based on the error too, not only start over, you can use `race` to indeed race between the two streams. First one to emit, wins; the other is unsubscribed.

```
action$
  .ofType(PAGINATION_CLICKED)
  .switchMap(() =>
    Observable.race(
      action$.ofType(FETCH_SUCCESS)
        .take(1)
        .map(() => analyticsAction()),
      action$.ofType(FETCH_ERROR)
        .take(1)
        .map(() => someOtherAnalyticsAction())
    )
  );
```

Here's the same thing, but using `race` as an instance operator instead of the static one. This is a stylistic preference you can choose. They both do the same thing. Use whichever one is more clear to you.

```
action$
  .ofType(PAGINATION_CLICKED)
  .switchMap(() =>
    action$.ofType(FETCH_SUCCESS)
      .map(() => analyticsAction())
      .race(
        action$.ofType(FETCH_ERROR)
          .map(() => someOtherAnalyticsAction())
      )
      .take(1)
  );
```

Comment: I almost got there! I ended up with your first example but without the (now obviously critical) `take(1)`. This basically meant the "sequence" was ignored after the first "PAGINATION_CLICKED". Thank you very much, great support for the library :)

Comment: Instead of race , is there a way i can indicate that i want both actions to be called/completed before producing the third action?

Comment: EDIT: nvm , i think i solved this with the zip operator.

Comment: Life-changing tip!

Comment: wouldn't it better to use exaustMap instead of switchMap in your first code example ? If the method analyticsAction() takes some times and and we received pagination_clicked action in the meantime, it will cancel the method analyticsAction()

Comment: @John perhaps. It all depends on what behavior a person wants. You may even want mergeMap. It's all up to you.