# Is it possible to wait for all actions in the ofType operator to be called before calling next?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I have an array of redux actions which when ALL have been called I want to call another action in my epic. The actions in the array are changeable, dynamic. What I'm hoping to find would be the equivalent of the `ofType` operator working like this:

`ofType(FETCH_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS && FETCH_USER_PREFERENCES_SUCCESS)`

When both actions have been called, another is called further down the pipe. Of course the `ofType` operator doesn't work like this. It only needs one of the actions to be called to continue.

I have read that `combineLatest` might be the solution here but I've had no luck. Below is what I imagine the solution could look like but obviously this doesn't work for me. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
const actions = ['FETCH_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS', 'FETCH_USER_PREFERENCES_SUCCESS'];

const asTypes = actions.map((action) => ofType(action);

const userEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    combineLatest(asTypes);
    mergeMap(() =>
      of({
        type: 'SET_USER_READY'
      })
    )
  );
```

Following on from replies below:

Just to clear what I meant by dynamic. The array of actions might include more actions depending on a user's profile (e.g. 'FETCH_USER_POSTS_SUCCESS'), essentially an unknown number of actions depending on the user.

So, is possible to generate this dynamically:

`zip(
    action$.pipe(ofType('FETCH_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS')),
    action$.pipe(ofType('FETCH_USER_PREFERENCES_SUCCESS')),
  )`

```
const actions = ['FETCH_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS', 'FETCH_USER_PREFERENCES_SUCCESS', unknown number of more actions];

const actions = dynamic.forEach((action) => action$.pipe(ofType(action))

zip(
    actions
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

why not making one general action like `executeAllActions` and inside this action payload you pass an array which contain all the references for all the actions you want like

```js
executeAllActions = {
    type: 'exectueAllActions',
    actionsList: [ fetchCategories, fetchProducts, ...],
}
```

then you listen for this action

```
this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType(executeAllActions),
   concatMap(action => [ ...actions.actionsList ])
)
```

where we used `concatMap` to return  a list of actoins that will all be executed.

I wish I can try this idea now, but I think it somehow possible.
If it works for you please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I understand this correctly, `ofType` doesn't call an action, it waits for the action to be called somewhere else, like a listener, but in concatMap above we are calling all the actions in the array?

Comment: yes, ofType is like a listener while what you return at the end should be an action(or a list of actions....) and that's why choosed concatMap over normal map.

Answer (score 0):

There's numerous ways of approaching this because there are some important missing details. But I'll make some guesses :)

The biggest is whether the order in which they arrive matters. If it does not, using `zip()` is probably what you want. It will pair emissions 1:1 (actually any number of observables, not just two, e.g. 1:1:1 for three, etc)

Even in that case, there's the question of what you want to do if the rate you receive the actions varies between them. What happens if you receive FETCH_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS's twice as fast as often as you receive FETCH_USER_PREFERENCES_SUCCESS's? Should you continue to buffer them? Do you drop them? Do you error?

If buffering them is fine or you otherwise provide guarantees they will always happen at the same rate, `zip()` is works.

---

Now if you want to make sure they come in some sequence, things get more complicated still. You'd likely have a chain utilizing mergeMap, switchMap, exhaustMap, or concatMap. Deciding which depends again on what you want to do if the rate you get the actions isn't always the same.

```
import { zip } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';

// Pair up the emissions 1:1 but without regard to the sequence
// in which they are received i.e. they can be in either order
const userEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  zip(
    action$.pipe(ofType('FETCH_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS')),
    action$.pipe(ofType('FETCH_USER_PREFERENCES_SUCCESS')),
    // ...etc more observables
  ).pipe(
    map(() => ({
      type: 'SET_USER_READY'
    }))
  );


// FETCH_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS must come before FETCH_USER_PREFERENCES_SUCCESS
// and if we receive another FETCH_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS before we get
// the FETCH_USER_PREFERENCES_SUCCESS, start over again (switchMap)
const userEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('FETCH_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS'),
    switchMap(() =>
      action$.pipe(
        ofType('FETCH_USER_PREFERENCES_SUCCESS'),
        take(1) // important! we only want to wait for one
      )
    ),
    map(() => ({
      type: 'SET_USER_READY'
    }))
  )
```

> The actions in the array are changeable, dynamic

It's not clear how you want them to change, so I didn't include a mechanism for doing so.

--

There's also a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45554647/1770633

Comment: That's great thank you. Just to clear what I meant by dynamic. The array of actions might include more actions depending on a user's profile (e.g. 'FETCH_USER_POSTS_SUCCESS'), essentially an unknown number of actions depending on the user.

So, is possible to generate this dynamically:

zip(
    action$.pipe(ofType('FETCH_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS')),
    action$.pipe(ofType('FETCH_USER_PREFERENCES_SUCCESS')),
  )

const actions = dynamic.forEach((action) => action$.pipe(ofType(action))

Comment: I added my reply to the original post so it's easier to read. Thank you

Comment: @theseboys sorry, it's still not clear where `dynamic` comes from, how it can change, etc

Comment: thanks for getting back. I'll come back to it again soon with more clarity. Cheers